# Lower bound on smallest eigenvalue calculation

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

I have to find the smallest $\sigma$ that satisfies the following expression:

$\lambda_{m}(A + \sigma I) < \delta, \quad \delta > 0$

where $A$ and $I$ (identity) are matrixes and $\lambda_{m}()$ is an opperator that returns the smallest eigenvalue of its argument.

So the question is: which is the smallest $\sigma$ such that $\lambda_{m}(A + \sigma I) < \delta$?

I have no ideia where to begin.

Comment: Does "smallest" here mean "least in absolute value", or what?  Are $\sigma$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ assumed to be real?  Positive?

Comment: Yes, smallest means least in absolute value, $\sigma$ must be greater than zero and the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.

Comment: If the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive and you require $\sigma > 0$, there is no such smallest $\sigma$: $\lambda_m(A + \sigma I) = \lambda_m(A) + \sigma$ is an increasing function of $\sigma$, so either there is no such $\sigma$ or you can take $\sigma$ arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  Could you give some context?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the lack of rigor on posting the question.

The problem I was trying to state is a problem related to mathematical optimization, more specifically related to the multidimensional modified Newton algorithm.

In this algorithm, one must define a $\delta > 0$ and find the smallest $\sigma \geq 0$ such that $$\lambda_{m}(\nabla^{2}f(x) + \sigma I) > \delta$$ where $\lambda_{m}()$ is an operator that returns its argument smallest eigenvalue, $x$ is a vector and $f$ is the function being minimized.

This whole procedure is performed in order to find a viable direction for finding the function's minimum.

Turns out the answer was much much simpler than what I expected. I had forgotten a basic property of matrices which states that $eigenvalues(A + kI) = eigenvalues(A) + k$. In this way, the answer to my question is simply $$\sigma > \delta - \lambda_{m}(\nabla^{2}f(x))$$